# Transparent Form Background HTML

Tags: html, css, forms

So I'm using this form from this site [here](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php)

When I post the form in my website the entire form area is white background. Yet I keep looking through the code and I don't see anything specifying the color. Is there a way to make it so that it has an opacity of 0 or anything of the like? Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps something in your stylesheet is adding the white background... the example shown in the link should be transparent by default

Comment: @arnaud Thanks. Ya I'll take a look cause his seems like it should be working, but the white is staying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this css rule:

```
#my_form
{
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Is that for within the html code or in the css? Sorry I'm pretty inexperienced with HTML

Comment: @steven this is fro the .css file. However, you can use directly in the form also, like this: `<form id="my_form" style="background-color: transparent;">`

Answer (score 3):

Background color is the answer as previously posted by dotoree however as a side tip, use this CSS class to change the opacity of a div.

```
.transparent {
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a rgba value for the background color.

`background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);` - white with a 50% transparency.